# Is this vector proof question wrong?

Tags: vectors

```
If a, b, c and d are not equal or 0 and (a.b)c=(b.c)a`, 
show that a and b are parallel.
```

Since the dot product is a scalar, I can see that c and a are scalar multiples of each other, but what if **b** is prependicular to **a** and **c**? Wont the given equation still be satisfied whilst allowing a and b to be anything in the plane perpendicular to *b*? What am I doing wrong here?

Sorry for the poor formatting. I have no idea how it works

Comment: You meant to say $a$ and $c$ are parallel, right?

Comment: Omg yes very sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are saying is correct. In $\mathbb R^{3}$ let $e_1,e_2,e_3$ be the standard basis. Take $a=e_1,b=e_2$ and $c=e_3$. Then the equation holds but $a$ and $c$ are linearly independent.

Comment: So there is no way to “prove this” without further information right?

Comment: Yes, it is false and there is no question of constructing a proof.  @o